# Android, Shared preferences and application update

Tags: android

I want my application to reset shared preferences when the application reinstalling

let's say i have in shared preferences IsfirstLunch property..

Now the application is installed , but i want to instal a newer version (without first uninstalling the existing one)

after the reinstall i want IsfirstLunch to be reset

Any way to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough :

Use your shared preference to store the current version of the app.

At every launch of the app compare the current version of the app with this stored preference.

If different then simply set your IsfirstLunch to true.

Getting the current app version :

```
try {
        String pkg = mContext.getPackageName();
        mVersionNumber = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg, 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        mVersionNumber = "?";
    }
```